# When trying to create a raid array with mdadm it says it failed to open the first disk listed

Tags: mdadm

When I try to set up raid in the terminal with mdadm it always comes up with this one problem, 
"mdadm: failed to open /dev/sdb1 after earlier success - aborting"
Anyone know how to fix this?